# JavaScript regex match doesn't return the full match

Tags: javascript, regex

I've posted an example here: http://codepen.io/ahamilton9/pen/hqmLc

Here's the JavaScript:

```
var content = 'This is my content which contains KEYWORD and should return seven words. ';
var regex = new RegExp('(?:(?:\w+\W*){0,3})' + 'keyword' + '(?:(?:\W*\w+){0,3})', 'gi');

var excerpts = regex.exec(content);
console.log(excerpts[0]);
```

Returns '**KEYWORD**' instead of '**content which contains KEYWORD and should return**'

I have no idea what's going on. I'm probably missing one symbol/flag or using the wrong function altogether. Online regex testers I've tried say the regex is sound, but I can't get the proper return. Help!

Comment: Double escape `\w` to `\\w` and `\W` to `\\W`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to escape the backslashes since you're creating the regex from the `new RegExp` construct:

```
var content = 'This is my content which contains KEYWORD and should return seven words. ';
var regex = new RegExp('(?:(?:\\w+\\W*){0,3})' + 'keyword' + '(?:(?:\\W*\\w+){0,3})', 'gi');

var excerpts = regex.exec(content);
alert(excerpts[0]);
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zBj8B/)

Comment: @ahamilton9 It's okay, you missed something that is not necessarily easily catchable :)

Answer (score 2):

```
(\\w+\\s){3}KEYWORD (\\w+\\s){2}\\w+
```